# Remove the dot in the middle of he circle

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am working on a project where the user can draw shapes and modify it (Size, Stroke etc). Then I encountered a problem, I tried to make the stroke thickness just to be adjusted inside so I did this code:

```
public void DrawCircle(Color c, int stroke, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;
        this.type = ShapeType.circle;


        w -= strokeThickness;
        h -= strokeThickness;
        PointF points = new PointF();
        //Centering the Shape
        points.X = (float)((center.X - (w/ 2)));
        points.Y = (float)((center.Y - (h / 2)));

        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

        //Drawing
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(points.X, points.Y, w, h);
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(c, stroke), rect);

    }
```

But whenever I save it (Save in a collection for repainting). It does something like this:

[image]

It shows dot in the exact center. It disappears after the picturebox.Refresh()/ Invalidate(); but I don't want it in the first place. What do you think is happening here?

Feel free to ask the parts of code you wanna know. I just presented the drawing part.

Comment: What is `center` in your code?

Comment: public PointF center = new PointF(250f,250f); Because my picturebox is 500,500

Comment: Put a Console.Debug(rect) after the DrawEllipse and the run your program in debug. Check that there is never a call that has a width and height of zero causing the centre point to appear.

Comment: {X=46.90552,Y=46.90552,Width=406.189,Height=406.189}
{X=251,Y=251,Width=-2,Height=-2} @PhilWright

Comment: @PhilWright the width and height seems to draw again with negative values

Comment: There is your problem, you need to work out why your getting two calls and why the second is for a -2 size.

Comment: Btw, `InterpolationMode` doesn't perform any smoothing here. It's primarily used to resize Bitmaps. You need to use the [Graphics.SmoothingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.smoothingmode). In this case, it should be set to `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias`. Also, since a Pen, used with defaul settings, draws half inside and half outside the rectangle boundaries, you could use [Rectangle.Inflate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.inflate) with negative values to reduce its size the half of the Pen size.